# Get a class of part it after typing. `keyup`

Tags: javascript, jquery

Why i always get a value(bu0) of typing in 3 field different(`class="bg_units bu0"`, `class="bg_units bu1"`, `class="bg_units bu2"`) ?

I want if user typing value in field bu0 get dynamic part 2 `class="bg_units bu0"` of class (.bu0), as for other:

- if typing each value on field bu0 =get class=> `.bu0`
- if typing each value on field bu1 =get class=> `.bu1`
- if typing each value on field bu2 =get class=> `.bu2`

**EXAMPLE:** http://jsfiddle.net/jJaYT/

```
$('.eghamat').live('keyup',function () {
    var $this = $(this),
    $div = $this.closest('div.find_input'),
    bu_num =  '.' + $div.find('.bg_units').attr('class').split(" ")[1];
    alert(bu_num);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should do this:

```
$('.eghamat').live('keyup', function() {
    var $this = $(this),
        $div = $this.closest('div.bg_units'),
        bu_num = '.' + $div.attr('class').split(" ")[1];
    alert(bu_num);
});
```

You are going up to the topmost div, which contains everything, searching for `.bg_units` and always getting the first one.  Just call `$this.closest('div.bg_units'),`

Answer (score 1):

You just needed a small change:

Working example : http://jsfiddle.net/jJaYT/2/

```
$('.eghamat').live('keyup',function () {
    $div = $(this).closest('.bg_units');
    bu_num =  '.' + $div.attr('class').split(" ")[1];
    alert(bu_num);
});
```